# Detect phone number with preg_replace with some specifics

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

It's a basic preg_replace that detects phone numbers (and just long numbers). My problem is I want to avoid detecting numbers between double `""`, single `''` and forward slashes `//`

`$text = preg_replace("/(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $text);`

I poked around but nothing is working for me. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I predict that your pattern is going to let you down more than it is going to satisfy you (or you are very comfortable with "over-matching" within the scope of your project).

While my suggestion really blows out the pattern length, a `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique will serve you well enough by consuming and discarding the substrings that require disqualification.  There may be a way of dictating the pattern logic with lookaround instead, but with an initial pattern with so many potential holes in it and no sample data, there are just too many variables to make a confident suggestion.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JdM0T5/1/)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g5Udc))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
A number 555555555 then some more text and a quoted number "(123)4567890" and
then 1 2 3 4     6 (54) 3 -2 and forward slashed /+--------0/ versus
+--------0 then something more realistic '234 588 9191' no more text.
This is not closed by the same character on both
ends: "+012345678901/ which of course is a _necessary_ check?
TEXT;

echo preg_replace(
         '~([\'"/])\+?[\d()\s-]{8,25}\d{1,2}\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|((?!\s)\+?[\d()\s-]{8,25}\d{1,2})~',
         "<strong>$2</strong>",
         $text);
```

Output:

```
A number <strong>555555555</strong> then some more text and a quoted number "(123)4567890" and
then <strong>1 2 3 4     6 (54) 3 -2</strong> and forward slashed /+--------0/ versus 
<strong>+--------0</strong> then something more realistic '234 588 9191' no more text.
This is not closed by the same character on both
ends: "<strong>+012345678901</strong>/ which of course is a _necessary_ check?
```

For the technical breakdown, see the Regex101 link.

Otherwise, this is effectively checking for "phone numbers" (by your initial pattern) and if they are wrapped by `'`, `"`, or `/` then the match is ignored and the regex engine continues looking for matches AFTER that substring.  I have added `(?!\s)` at the start of the second usage of your phone pattern so that leading spaces are omitted from the replacement.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're not validating, then you might be trying to write some expression with less boundaries, such as:

```
^\+?[0-9()\s-]{8,25}[0-9]$
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8RUrf5/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8RUrf5/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: This answer does nothing to disqualify the specific substrings expressed in the question.  It assumes there is no other text involved.